# Transfer a lock to a spawned thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Is there a way to do something like this in Java (possibly using `Lock` instead of `synchronized`):

```
synchronized(lock) {

     Thread t = spawnThread(new Runnable() {

         synchronized(lock) {
            doThing();
         }

     });

     transferLockOwnership(lock, t);

}
```

Specifically, I'd like to replace code like this:

```
    synchronized (lock) {

        sendResponse(response);

        doThingsAfterSending();

    }
```

With something like this:

```
    synchronized (lock) {

        Thread t = spawnThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) { doThingsAfterSending(); }
        }});

        transferLockOwnership(lock, t);

        return response;

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using a `Semaphore` with 1 permit? E.g.

```
private Semaphore lock= new Semaphore(1);


// Instead of synchronized(lock)
lock.acquireUninterruptibly();

Thread t = spawnThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    try {
      // Do stuff.
    } finally {
      lock.release();
    }
  }
});

t.start();
```

Comment: is it allowed for a different thread to release than the one that acquired?

Comment: Yes, a Semaphore is simply a thread-safe counter with some blocking methods.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. A `Lock` and a monitor as used by `synchronized` can only be held by a single thread. And "moving" it to another requires releasing the lock and re-acquiring, which includes the danger of *another* thread getting it instead of the desired one.

*If* you need something like this, you'll have to build it yourself from the basic blocks: producer your own `Lock`-like class that *uses* `Lock` to be thread-safe, but which provides a `transferToThread()` method.